# Can't setImage

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uiimageview

Noob Alert,

I am trying to change an image in a UIImageView.

popCard is the IBOutlet pointed to the UIImageView - which is blank in IB.

there are 5 possible images (Graphic0, Graphic1, etc.)

For some reason it keeps displaying Graphic1.

I got a feeling I'm missing something simple. Can you help please?

This what i am using:

```
getCard=0;
 NSLog(@"begin showCard = %i",getCard);
 FlowCoverAppDelegate *mainDelegate = (FlowCoverAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
 getCard = mainDelegate.showCard;
 NSLog(@"showCard = %i",getCard);

 if (getCard = 0) {
     [popCard setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Graphic0.jpg"]];
     popCard.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
     return;
 }
```

Cheers
Paul

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The issue with your code is the following**:

You are assigning `getCard` to `0` in your `if` expression, change it to `==`.

Also, if `getCard` is not a property of your object, you need to declare it as `int getCard = 0;`

**What you should do**:

Instead of writing 5 `if` statements, just write this one line:

```
[popCard setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: [ NSString stringWithFormat: @"Graphic%d.jpg", getCard ] ] ];
```

Comment: that's why some prefer to write if (0 == getCard)

Comment: Thank you! That's the second time == caught me out.

Vladmir - I really like that format. It'll help me remember.